# Connect additional column in excel to a Data source table

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

I have a PowerApp which I use to add items (rows) (from an inspection) to a list in Sharepoint. This sharepoint list I import in Excel using "Get Data" and the whole sharepoint URL, etc. In Excel I want to add a comment to a particular item (row). However when I add a new item to the list. The comment will stay stuck in say cell F5, while the new item added to the sharepoint list pushes the rest of the list down, do the item the comment is about has shifted to row G.

**How can I connect the additional column to the information from the imported table?**